# Remove Unwanted shadowing with LineIntegralConvolutionPlot

Tags: graphics, nonlinear

I draw a [*StreamPlot*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html) using

```
  StreamPlot[{2 - 3*x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2}, {x, - 3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

This correctly produces

[image]

Next, I use [*LineIntegralConvolutionPlot*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineIntegralConvolutionPlot.html)

```
  LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{{2 - 3*x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2}, {"noise",  500, 500}}, 
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> "BeachColors",LightingAngle -> 0, 
  LineIntegralConvolutionScale -> 3, Frame -> False]
```

This produces

[image]

Other variants are doing the same thing, for example,

```
   LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{{2 - 3*x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2}, {Automatic, 500, 64}}, 
   {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",Frame -> False, 
   LightingAngle -> 0]
```

Is there any way to get rid of the shadowing in the RHS of the image so it looks more like the LHS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this what you want?

```
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{{2 - 3*x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2}, {"noise", 
   500, 500}}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> "BeachColors",
  LineIntegralConvolutionScale -> 3, Frame -> False]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: That is closer. The shadowing at the top center of the diagram is bothersome. Can that be removed?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Yes, that is it, thanks! It is unfortunate that it loses some of the beautiful details from the original.

Answer (score 5):

If you want lighting without shadows (as opposed to `None`), set the altitude high (as shown in the docs):

```
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{{2 - 3*x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2}, {"noise", 
   500, 500}}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "BeachColors",
 LightingAngle -> {0, Pi/2}, (* angle, altitude *)
 LineIntegralConvolutionScale -> 3, Frame -> False]
```

[image]